# Word VBA placing text in a table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to place text in a table in MS Word, the table consist of a Header in the first row and 2 columns and then another row for where the text should go.

The text to fill the Table is in a UserForm more precisely TextBox3

So if TextBox3 contains:

Automotive Registered Services Manager

I want the table to look like these:

```
 Header#1  | Header#2

Automotive | 85,000 
Registered | 77,000 
Services   | 32,000 
Manager    | 500,00
```

The numbers from Header#2 come from a database from excel that part I can either decide to do it manually or work on it later if I get stucked I will ask for help but for now what I'm struggling with is the table since I only have 1 row in which I want to paste the info,

I tried using:

```
Dim tmpArray As Variant
tmpArray = Split(TextBox3, " ")


Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To UBound(tmpArray)

    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(i, 1).Range = tmpArray(i - 1)
    Selection.TypeParagraph



Next i
```

But even I have the `TypeParagraph` the code only writes the second word, let me give you the whole code and see what we can come up with.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
With ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("bmCN").Range _
    .InsertBefore TextBox1
    .Bookmarks("bmOriJob").Range _
    .InsertBefore TextBox2
    .Bookmarks("bmOptJob").Range _
    .InsertBefore TextBox3
    .Bookmarks("bmJobD").Range _
    .InsertBefore TextBox4
    .Bookmarks("bmJobRes").Range _
    .InsertBefore TextBox5
    .Bookmarks("bmJobR").Range _
    .InsertBefore TextBox6
    .Bookmarks("bmBen").Range _
    .InsertBefore TextBox7
    .Bookmarks("bmTag").Range _
    .InsertBefore TextBox8
End With
'Temporary array
Dim tmpArray As Variant
    tmpArray = Split(TextBox3, " ")


Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To UBound(tmpArray)

    ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(i, 1).Range = tmpArray(i - 1)
    Selection.TypeParagraph



Next i
UserForm1.Hide
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Fields.Update
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
End Sub
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the array indexing in your loop.  Since the maximum value for `i` is `UBound(tmpArray)` and you're setting cells to `tmpArray(i - 1)`, you will always omit the last array element.  You are also starting in your header row (`Cell(1, 1)` on the first time through the loop). Finally, working directly with the document's Range objects doesn't effect which Range is selected, so `Selection.TypeParagraph` will always be wherever the selection was prior to running the code.  In that this is in your loop, I'm guessing that this isn't the desired behavior.  Finally, you should probably just grab a reference to `ActiveDocument` at the first opportunity and pass that between Subs as needed. Not only is it more efficient than continually dereferencing the Global, it avoids situations where user interaction might *change* the active document while code is running.

Something like this should work:

```
Dim doc As Document
Set doc = ActiveDocument

'...

Dim tmpArray As Variant
tmpArray = Split(TextBox3.Text, " ")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To UBound(tmpArray)
    doc.Tables(1).Cell(i + 2, 1).Range = tmpArray(i)
Next i
```

Comment: Hi @Comintern tried it but its not working I get the same behavior just the last word remains in the table